# How to run Skyrim in wine using primusrun?

Tags: wine, steam, bumblebee, playonlinux

When I `cd` into a directory containing a .exe that I can run in Wine, how do I run that .exe with `primusrun`?

Specifically, I have installed Skyrim via Steam on PlayOnLinux. I've successfully run other games in Wine, without PlayOnLinux active. But for Skyrim, the game's framerate renders it almost unplayable, even on the lowest settings. I want to run it through `primusrun` (Bumblebee), so it will use my Nvidia GeForce graphics card instead of the default Intel. Adding `primusrun` to the command on the shortcut properties allows the game to run using the card, but the game blackscreens after the Bethesda logo, only working properly about 2% of the time.

When I `cd` into the directory containing TESV.exe, then execute the command `primusrun wine TESV.exe` in terminal, it just shows a new line as if the command was successfully executed. However, nothing happens to show that that is the case. Nothing launches.

So, to summarize, how do I run Skyrim in Wine from the terminal or via a script, using `primusrun` to designate my Nvidia graphics card as the one to use? Or else, if this is not possible, can someone link me to some directions on how to fix the blackscreen on launch?

Answer (score 1):

While this is still an issue for me, I've found a workaround.

By adding `primusrun` to the shortcut, it reliably launches in fully functional form the first time after rebooting my machine. Any subsequent launches are likely to blackscreen, but the first one almost always works.

Another workaround is to install SKSE (Skyrim Script Extender), create a PlayOnLinux shortcut for SKSE.exe, and add `primusrun` to the shortcut properties as well. This runs reliably about 80% of the time, with no need for rebooting between launches. Useful for when your game crashes randomly.

Please note, however, that when you close Skyrim, the process does not end properly, so you have to open System Monitor and kill it, or else use the `kill` command in terminal. Other than that, though, it works pretty well!