# Dark Souls crashes on launch under PlayOnLinux Wine

Tags: wine, steam, bumblebee, primus

After a fair amount of trial and error, I've managed to create a shortcut on my desktop that runs Dark Souls: Prepare to Die Edition through Steam, through Wine, and edited it to run through primus, like I did here: [How to run Skyrim in wine using primusrun?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/578581/how-to-run-skyrim-in-wine-using-primusrun/601250#601250)

Now, the problem is, when I run it, it opens the window, then jumps as if it's going to go fullscreen... and freezes. I don't know what's causing this, and I had it working before I reverted Intel drivers (as they were breaking bumblebee, and nvidia drivers in general). I believe that reinstalling the Intel driver would solve the launch problem, but that would disable bumblebee again, resulting in a metric crap-ton of lag, and rendering the game unplayable (literally, as the game kicks you out if your framerate is below a certain point).

I've run the PlayOnLinux program through the Debug option, and this is what the log says:

```
m32<elf>
  \-PE  7db70000-7db92000   \               imm32
ELF 7dbeb000-7dc14000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF 7dc14000-7dc57000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF 7dc57000-7dc83000   Deferred        libpng12.so.0
ELF 7dc83000-7dd33000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF 7dd60000-7dd8a000   Deferred        msacm32<elf>
  \-PE  7dd70000-7dd8a000   \               msacm32
ELF 7dd8a000-7de42000   Deferred        winmm<elf>
  \-PE  7dd90000-7de42000   \               winmm
ELF 7de42000-7df4a000   Deferred        comctl32<elf>
  \-PE  7de50000-7df4a000   \               comctl32
ELF 7df4a000-7e037000   Deferred        comdlg32<elf>
  \-PE  7df50000-7e037000   \               comdlg32
ELF 7e037000-7e079000   Deferred        winspool<elf>
  \-PE  7e040000-7e079000   \               winspool
ELF 7e079000-7e095000   Deferred        jsproxy<elf>
  \-PE  7e080000-7e095000   \               jsproxy
ELF 7e095000-7e0d1000   Deferred        winhttp<elf>
  \-PE  7e0a0000-7e0d1000   \               winhttp
ELF 7e0d1000-7e10f000   Deferred        d3d9<elf>
  \-PE  7e0e0000-7e10f000   \               d3d9
ELF 7e10f000-7e258000   Deferred        wined3d<elf>
  \-PE  7e120000-7e258000   \               wined3d
ELF 7e258000-7e2cd000   Deferred        ddraw<elf>
  \-PE  7e260000-7e2cd000   \               ddraw
ELF 7e2cd000-7e410000   Deferred        oleaut32<elf>
  \-PE  7e2f0000-7e410000   \               oleaut32
ELF 7e410000-7e495000   Deferred        rpcrt4<elf>
  \-PE  7e420000-7e495000   \               rpcrt4
ELF 7e495000-7e5d7000   Deferred        ole32<elf>
  \-PE  7e4b0000-7e5d7000   \               ole32
ELF 7e5d7000-7e67b000   Deferred        urlmon<elf>
  \-PE  7e5e0000-7e67b000   \               urlmon
ELF 7e67b000-7e6b3000   Deferred        ws2_32<elf>
  \-PE  7e680000-7e6b3000   \               ws2_32
ELF 7e6b3000-7e8eb000   Deferred        shell32<elf>
  \-PE  7e6c0000-7e8eb000   \               shell32
ELF 7e8eb000-7e965000   Deferred        shlwapi<elf>
  \-PE  7e900000-7e965000   \               shlwapi
ELF 7e965000-7e97e000   Deferred        version<elf>
  \-PE  7e970000-7e97e000   \               version
ELF 7e97e000-7ea97000   Deferred        gdi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e990000-7ea97000   \               gdi32
ELF 7ea97000-7ebf4000   Deferred        user32<elf>
  \-PE  7eab0000-7ebf4000   \               user32
ELF 7ebf4000-7ec1b000   Deferred        mpr<elf>
  \-PE  7ec00000-7ec1b000   \               mpr
ELF 7ec1b000-7ec99000   Deferred        wininet<elf>
  \-PE  7ec20000-7ec99000   \               wininet
ELF 7ec99000-7ed0a000   Deferred        advapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7ecb0000-7ed0a000   \               advapi32
ELF 7ed0a000-7ed23000   Deferred        libresolv.so.2
ELF 7ed37000-7ed50000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF 7ed50000-7ed5e000   Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF 7ed5e000-7ed6b000   Deferred        libnss_nis.so.2
ELF 7ed6b000-7ed86000   Deferred        libnsl.so.1
ELF 7ef86000-7efd3000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF 7efda000-7f000000   Deferred        iphlpapi<elf>
  \-PE  7efe0000-7f000000   \               iphlpapi
ELF f7344000-f734e000   Deferred        libnss_compat.so.2
ELF f734f000-f7354000   Deferred        libdl.so.2
ELF f7354000-f750f000   Deferred        libc.so.6
ELF f750f000-f752c000   Deferred        libpthread.so.0
ELF f7551000-f755a000   Deferred        librt.so.1
ELF f755a000-f7710000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF f7712000-f7736000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
ELF f7738000-f7739000   Deferred        [vdso].so
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
00000008 Steam.exe
    0000005c    0
    00000058    0
    00000056    0
    00000054    0
    00000053    0
    00000052    0
    00000051    0
    00000050    0
    0000004f    0
    0000004e    0
    0000004d    0
    0000004c    0
    0000004b    0
    0000004a    0
    00000049    0
    00000048    0
    00000035    0
    0000002f    0
    0000002e    0
    0000002d    0
    0000002c    0
    00000029    0
    00000028    0
    00000009    0
0000000e services.exe
    00000023    0
    00000022    0
    0000001b    0
    00000014    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
00000012 mscorsvw.exe
    00000018    0
    00000017    0
    00000013    0
00000019 winedevice.exe
    00000021    0
    0000001e    0
    0000001d    0
    0000001a    0
0000001f plugplay.exe
    00000025    0
    00000024    0
    00000020    0
00000026 explorer.exe
    00000027    0
0000002a steamwebhelper.exe
    0000006e    0
    0000005b    0
    00000055    0
    0000000b    0
    0000000d    0
    0000000c    0
    00000047    0
    00000046    0
    00000045    0
    00000044    0
    00000043    0
    00000042    0
    00000041    0
    00000040    0
    0000003f    0
    0000003e    0
    0000003d    0
    0000003c    0
    0000003b    0
    0000003a    0
    00000039    0
    00000038    0
    00000037    0
    00000036    0
    0000002b    0
00000059 steamwebhelper.exe
    00000077    0
    00000076    0
    00000031    0
    00000067    0
    00000066    0
    00000065    0
    00000064    0
    00000063    0
    00000062    0
    00000061    0
    00000060    0
    0000005a    0
00000069 (D) C:\Program Files\Steam\SteamApps\common\Epic Battle Fantasy 4\EBF4.exe
    0000006a    0 <==
Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 105600
Steam_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Caching Steam ID:  76561198090181781 [API loaded no]
[06/20/15 08:50:56] - Running wine-1.7.36 DARKSOULS.exe (Working directory : /home/ctrlfreak1337/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/terraria/drive_c/Program Files/Steam/SteamApps/common/Dark Souls Prepare to Diefixme:advapi:EventRegister {47a9201e-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361bc6f}, 0x3f0069e0, 0x3f040cf0, 0x3f040ce8
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {58a9201e-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361bc70}, 0x3f0069e0, 0x3f040d28, 0x3f040d20
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {3fa9201e-73b0-43fe-9821-7e145359bc6f}, 0x3f0069e0, 0x3f040cb8, 0x3f040cb0
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {1432afee-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361b433}, 0x3f0069e0, 0x3f040d60, 0x3f040d58
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {4372afee-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361b519}, 0x3f0069e0, 0x3f040d98, 0x3f040d90
fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x31efd0 (nil)): stub
fixme:ntdll:NtQuerySystemInformation info_class SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x384538) stub
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x101ba938) stub
[06/20/15 08:52:08] - Running wine-1.7.36 Steam.exe (Working directory : /home/ctrlfreak1337/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/terraria/drive_c/Program Files/Steam)
[06/20/15 08:54:38] - Running wine-1.7.36 winecfg (Working directory : /usr/share/playonlinux/python)
[06/20/15 08:55:37] - Running wine-1.7.36 DARKSOULS.exe steam://rungameid/211420 (Working directory : /home/ctrlfreak1337/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/terraria/drive_c/Program Files/Steam/SteamApps/common/[06/20/15 08:55:45] - Running wine-1.7.36 DARKSOULS.exe steam://rungameid/211420 (Working directory : /home/ctrlfreak1337/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/terraria/drive_c/Program Files/Steam/SteamApps/common/fixme:advapi:EventRegister {47a9201e-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361bc6f}, 0x3f0069e0, 0x3f040cf0, 0x3f040ce8
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {58a9201e-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361bc70}, 0x3f0069e0, 0x3f040d28, 0x3f040d20
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {3fa9201e-73b0-43fe-9821-7e145359bc6f}, 0x3f0069e0, 0x3f040cb8, 0x3f040cb0
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {1432afee-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361b433}, 0x3f0069e0, 0x3f040d60, 0x3f040d58
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {4372afee-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361b519}, 0x3f0069e0, 0x3f040d98, 0x3f040d90
fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x31efd0 (nil)): stub
fixme:ntdll:NtQuerySystemInformation info_class SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x384538) stub
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x101ba938) stub
[06/20/15 08:56:54] - Running wine-1.7.36 Steam.exe steam://rungameid/105600 (Working directory : /home/ctrlfreak1337/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/terraria/drive_c/Program Files/Steam)
fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x33e490 (nil)): stub
Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 105600
Steam_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Caching Steam ID:  76561198090181781 [API loaded no]
[0620/085703:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(212)] Running without renderer sandbox
[06/20/15 08:59:10] - Running wine-1.7.36 Steam.exe steam://rungameid/211420 (Working directory : /home/ctrlfreak1337/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/terraria/drive_c/Program Files/Steam)
ALSA lib pcm_hw.c:1667:(_snd_pcm_hw_open) Invalid value for card
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  72 (X_PutImage)
  Serial number of failed request:  56
  Current serial number in output stream:  89
[06/20/15 08:59:47] - Running wine-1.7.36 Steam.exe steam://rungameid/211420 (Working directory : /home/ctrlfreak1337/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/terraria/drive_c/Program Files/Steam)
ALSA lib pcm_hw.c:1667:(_snd_pcm_hw_open) Invalid value for card
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  72 (X_PutImage)
  Serial number of failed request:  56
  Current serial number in output stream:  89
[06/20/15 09:07:09] - Running wine-1.7.36 Steam.exe steam://rungameid/105600 (Working directory : /home/ctrlfreak1337/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/terraria/drive_c/Program Files/Steam)
Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 105600
Steam_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Caching Steam ID:  76561198090181781 [API loaded no]
[06/20/15 09:10:24] - Running wine-1.7.36 Steam.exe steam://rungameid/211420 (Working directory : /home/ctrlfreak1337/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/terraria/drive_c/Program Files/Steam)
ALSA lib pcm_hw.c:1667:(_snd_pcm_hw_open) Invalid value for card
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  72 (X_PutImage)
  Serial number of failed request:  56
  Current serial number in output stream:  89
[06/20/15 09:11:35] - Running wine-1.7.36 Steam.exe steam://rungameid/211420 (Working directory : /home/ctrlfreak1337/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/terraria/drive_c/Program Files/Steam)
fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x33e490 (nil)): stub
ALSA lib pcm_hw.c:1667:(_snd_pcm_hw_open) Invalid value for card
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  72 (X_PutImage)
  Serial number of failed request:  56
  Current serial number in output stream:  89
ALSA lib pcm.c:7843:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
ALSA lib pcm.c:7843:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
ALSA lib pcm.c:7843:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
ALSA lib pcm.c:7843:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
ALSA lib pcm.c:7843:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
ALSA lib pcm.c:7843:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
ALSA lib pcm.c:7843:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
ALSA lib pcm.c:7843:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
ALSA lib pcm.c:7843:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
ALSA lib pcm.c:7843:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
ALSA lib pcm.c:7843:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
ALSA lib pcm.c:7843:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
ALSA lib pcm.c:7843:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
ALSA lib pcm.c:7843:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
ALSA lib pcm.c:7843:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
ALSA lib pcm.c:7843:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
ALSA lib pcm.c:7843:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
ALSA lib pcm.c:7843:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
ALSA lib pcm.c:7843:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
ALSA lib pcm.c:7843:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
ALSA lib pcm.c:7843:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
ALSA lib pcm.c:7843:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
ALSA lib pcm.c:7843:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
ALSA lib pcm.c:7843:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
ALSA lib pcm.c:7843:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
ALSA lib pcm.c:7843:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
ALSA lib pcm.c:7843:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
ALSA lib pcm.c:7843:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
```

I can't pinpoint the cause. Can anyone help?

An alternative solution would be to find out how to get Wine to recognize my Nvidia graphics card without using bumblebee, but I haven't found anything like that yet, and with the Intel DRM update that broke Nvidia drivers, I don't know if that would work anyway.

Comment: I have reverted to the updated drivers. My game now works without primus, but the controls have a habit of sticking, and the game kicks me to the title menu after a few seconds because of low framerate. I've tried lowering the quality to no avail.

Comment: What's your nvidia hardware and what's the version of drivers you're using?

Comment: @Fabby I have a GeForce 745m card, and I'm using version 346.59 from nvidia-346-updates.

Comment: Could you try [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers) first then?  I'm running 352.21 and don't have the problem (any more)...

Comment: @Fabby I previously didn't have the ppa:mamarley repository added, so that may have been part of my problem, haha. I'll test it in the morning, but I've already seen a reassuring sign- upon login, Ubuntu used to throw me three "System Program Program Detected" windows. They disappeared after the Intel driver update, but after the reboot, they reappeared... I'll take this as a good sign. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Fabby Just tried running Steam in Wine with Primus... no dice. It stops responding at the "Connecting to Steam Account" stage. Tried my basic test, running PCSX2, which also failed because it couldn't load the GPU driver, which it's been doing since the Intel update. I just installed nvidia-352, not sure if that's 352.21 or not.

Comment: I'm out of ideas...  :(

Comment: @Fabby Hang on, it might be something different. I didn't check the logs for any of the aforementioned tests. While running Minecraft (which ALWAYS gives a log), it didn't say "failed to load GPU driver", it said "econdary X is not active". I've just checked PCSX2's log, and it says the same. So the driver itself is no longer the issue...

Comment: Well, I tweaked something that set me back to square one... I don't know what. I've tried jumping around from solution to solution trying to cobble something together, to no avail... I've even tried purging both bumblebee and nvidia, then reinstalling both; no dice....

Answer (score 3):

IT LIVES!!!

After quite a bit of trial and error, I got it working! I had to go into my bumblebee.conf and set `Driver=nvidia` and then go and change the `[driver-nvidia]` settings from `nvidia-current` to `nvidia-352`, then manually set the BusID in `/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia`, but now it works!

...Hopefully it'll stay working...

Comment: :D  Good!  (upvoted!) Hopefully someone else will be able to prune some benefit from your work!